# How can I use a custom 'id' object to look up elements in a Java Collection?

Tags: java, collections

So I currently have an `ArrayList<Page>`. `ArrayList` does not fit all my needs, which are:

- retrieve a `Page` from the collection by **index**
- retrieve a `Page` from the collection by **`ContentId`**
- The ordering of the collection is defined by the order objects are added to it (note: not through a comparator). `Page` is a view model, which is why I want to keep it as dumb as possible.

What collection should I use that can satisfy the above requirements? Below are my classes

**Page.java**

```
public class Page {
    final String title;
    final String subtitle;

    final String html;

    //unique identifier
    final ContentId contentId;

    boolean bookmarked;
}
```

**ContentId.java**

```
public class ContentId implements Parcelable {
    final ContentType type; //enum
    final long id;
}
```

Comment: How do you add to an immutable collection?

Comment: @PaulBoddington you can make it unmodifiable. I removed that part about Immutability as its not core to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appears to be for Android, you could use an [`ArrayMap<ContentId, Page>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html).  The superclass method [`valueAt(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap.html#valueAt%28int%29) satisfies your first requirement; `get(Object)` from the `Map` interface satisfies the second; and it preserves insertion order.  You'll probably want to override `equals(...)` and `hashcode()` in `ContentId`.  The docs mention that `ArrayMap` can be slower than `HashMap`, but...

> For containers holding up to hundreds of items, the performance difference is not significant, less than 50%.

Comment: This looks perfect! I will be passing the `ContentId`, like `arrayMap.get(contentId)` to get the right `Page` instance. How do I ensure a `ContentId` instance correctly lines up with the appropriate `Page` instance?

Comment: @ZakTaccardi I'm not sure I understand your question about things lining up.  The `put(ContentId, Page)` method will associate a `ContentId` with a `Page`.  Just don't `put` the same `ContentId` twice or you'll overwrite its association with a previous `Page`.  The "sameness" of map keys is determined by the `equals(...)` method of the key class.

Comment: Krumewiede oops sorry, not sure why I asked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily wrap ArrayList with your own class to expose only the functionality you want. I believe the Pages class below meets your requirements:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Pages {
    private final List<Page> pageList;
    public Pages() {
        this.pageList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(Page page) {
        this.pageList.add(page);
    }

    public Page get(int index) {
        return this.pageList.get(index);
    }

    public Page get(ContentId contentId)
    {
        return this.pageList.stream()
                .filter(page -> page.getContentId().equals(contentId))
                .findFirst().get();
    }
}
```